# Get the content of all tags AFTER THE FIRST of the SAME tags - Jsoup

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

Trying to gather some website content using jsoup and have run into a problem with the collection of some information.
What I would like to do is gather the content of all the p tags **after** the **first** of x amount of p tags *( x being an unknown number could be 1-10)*:

[image]

I know that you can collect the first like this:

```
.select("div#news_content_wide > p").first();
```

but is there a way to select the content AFTER the first without knowing the amount you want?

Thanks

Comment: `div#news_content_wide > p~p`?

Comment: @Musa Just tried it... Genius, Thank you and the Tilde. Do you want to pop it in an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `div#news_content_wide > p~p` it uses the [general sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators)

What happens here is that any `p` who has a sibling `p` precedence it will be selected, so basically all but the first.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function taking the target div as a parameter and the paragraph element you don't want to return... I.E. '1' (actually zero)...

```
<body>

<script>

      function removeElement( div, num ) {
        var parent = document.getElementById( div );
        var returnElems = [];
        if( parent.children.length > 1 && parent.children[0].nodeType === 1 ) {
            if( parent.children[0].tagName === "P") {
                var paras = parent.children;

                for( var i = 0; i < paras.length; i++) {
                    if( i != (num - 1) ) {
                        returnElems.push(paras[i]);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
          return returnElems;

      }

  </script>

<div id="news_content_wide">
    <p>DON'T RETURN THIS</p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
</body>
```

#### CONSOLE

```
var elems = removeElement("news_content_wide", 1);
console.log(elems);
```